# Is there a way to export the uv layout png without aliased black lines?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image]Is there anyway for uv export images not to have this aliasing feature? Like be able to get solid black lines only.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOWw0.jpg

Comment: Export it in svg format.

Answer (score 1):

In the UV exporter window you can choose svg format instead of png in the left side panel.
[image]